# Java Quiz with GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, service

Hey there I am trying to build a quiz program for my English class Christmas party. It has a GUI and all but this is not important there. I have three buttons each bearing the tag of either Answer A, B , or C.
I have a Button Go that fills in the first Question from an array. All the other Questions are stores in an array as well but each in a different one. They are named frage 1-10. They contains the Question three possible answers and a string that tells the program which one is the correct one. I need a service called nextQuestion that will fill in the next array into the corresponding fields. I struggle with this service as I can not think of any way to do so. I will post my source code here in the hope that you can help me with this. As I am German the code contains multi language parts. If you are struggling to understand do not hesitate to ask I will try my best to explain my scrubby code.
I thank you in advance for your support.

```
import sum.komponenten.*;
import sum.werkzeuge.*;
import sum.ereignis.*;

public class DasQuiz extends EBAnwendung
{
    // Objekte

private Etikett hatEtikettHeader;

private Knopf hatKnopfAnswerA;

private Knopf hatKnopfExit;

private Knopf hatKnopfAnswerB;

private Knopf hatKnopfAnswerC;

private Zeichenbereich hatZeichenbereichQuestion;

private Etikett hatEtikett2;

private Etikett hatEtikett3;

private Etikett hatEtikett4;

private Etikett hatEtikettTeamOne;

private Etikett hatEtikettTemaTwo;

private Etikett hatEtikettPunkte1;

private Etikett hatEtikettPunkte2;

private Knopf hatKnopfGo;

private String[] frage1 = new String[]{"What is traditionally hidden in a Christmas pudding?", "A Coin", "A Watch", "A pair of dice", "A"};

private String[] frage2 = new String[]{"How many days are there on a traditional advent calendar?", "12", "24", "30", "B"};

private String[] frage3 = new String[]{"____pull Santa's sleigh", "Guniea Pigs", "Cats", "Reindeers", "C"};

private String[] frage4 = new String[]{"According to the song, how many days of Christmas are there?", "11", "12", "13", "B"};

private String[] frage5 = new String[]{"Why do we shorten Christmas to Xmas?", "X is the first letter of the Greek word for Christ", "X looks like a snowflake", "X looks like a star", "A"};

private String[] frage6 = new String[]{"What is the last day of Christmas called?", "Advent", "Twelfth Night", "Boxing Day", "B"};

private String[] frage7 = new String[]{"Are used to make traditional Christingles", "Peaches", "Pears", "Oranges", "C"};

private String[] frage8 = new String[]{"Charles _____ wrote the book A Christmas Carol", "Dahl", "Rowling", "Dickens", "C"};  

private String[] frage9 = new String[]{"Which royal couple started off the fashion for Christmas trees in Britain?", "King Henry adn Anne Boleyn", "Queen Victoria adn Prince Albert", "Prince William and kate Middleton", "B"};

private String[] frage10 = new String[]{"Which of these plants is traditionally connected with Christmas?", "Daisy", "Daffodil", "Poinsettia", "C"};

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


// Attribute
/**
 * Konstruktor
 */
public DasQuiz()
{
    //Initialisierung der Oberklasse
    super(1255, 876);

    hatEtikettHeader = new Etikett(468, 57, 225, 25, "Christmas Quiz LK English by Marc Blaesche");
    // Ausrichtung
    hatEtikettHeader.setzeAusrichtung(Ausrichtung.LINKS);
    hatKnopfAnswerA = new Knopf(289, 472, 100, 25, "Answer A");
    hatKnopfAnswerA.setzeBearbeiterGeklickt("hatSchalterAnswerAGeklickt");
    hatKnopfExit = new Knopf(1078, 810, 100, 25, "Exit");
    hatKnopfExit.setzeBearbeiterGeklickt("hatKnopfExitGeklickt");
    hatKnopfAnswerB = new Knopf(514, 472, 100, 25, "Answer B");
    hatKnopfAnswerB.setzeBearbeiterGeklickt("hatSchalterAnswerBGeklickt");
    hatKnopfGo = new Knopf (514, 397, 100, 25, "GOGO");
    hatKnopfGo.setzeBearbeiterGeklickt("hatKnopfGoGeklickt");
    hatKnopfAnswerC = new Knopf(755, 472, 100, 25, "Answer C");
    hatKnopfAnswerC.setzeBearbeiterGeklickt("hatSchalterAnswerCGeklickt");
    hatZeichenbereichQuestion = new Zeichenbereich(288, 143, 566, 143, "");
    hatEtikett2 = new Etikett(289, 300, 566, 25, "");
    // Ausrichtung
    hatEtikett2.setzeAusrichtung(Ausrichtung.LINKS);
    hatEtikett3 = new Etikett(289, 340, 566, 25, "");
    // Ausrichtung
    hatEtikett3.setzeAusrichtung(Ausrichtung.LINKS);
    hatEtikett4 = new Etikett(289, 380, 566, 25, "");
    // Ausrichtung
    hatEtikett4.setzeAusrichtung(Ausrichtung.LINKS);
    hatEtikettTeamOne = new Etikett(72, 585, 100, 25, "Team One");
    // Ausrichtung
    hatEtikettTeamOne.setzeAusrichtung(Ausrichtung.LINKS);
    hatEtikettTemaTwo = new Etikett(356, 586, 100, 25, "Tema Two");
    // Ausrichtung
    hatEtikettTemaTwo.setzeAusrichtung(Ausrichtung.LINKS);
    hatEtikettPunkte1 = new Etikett(72, 671, 100, 141, "");
    // Ausrichtung
    hatEtikettPunkte1.setzeAusrichtung(Ausrichtung.LINKS);
    hatEtikettPunkte2 = new Etikett(355, 669, 96, 141, "");
    // Ausrichtung
    hatEtikettPunkte2.setzeAusrichtung(Ausrichtung.LINKS);
}


public void hatKnopfAnswerAGeklickt()
{

}

public void hatKnopfExitGeklickt()
{
    System.exit(0);
}


public void hatKnopfAnswerBGeklickt()
{
    //    Schreiben Sie hier den Text ihres Dienstes
}

public void hatKnopfAnswerCGeklickt()
{
    //    Schreiben Sie hier den Text ihres Dienstes
}

    public void hatKnopfGoGeklickt()
{
    hatZeichenbereichQuestion.setzeInhalt(frage1[0]);
    hatEtikett2.setzeInhalt(frage1[1]);
    hatEtikett3.setzeInhalt(frage1[2]);
    hatEtikett4.setzeInhalt(frage1[3]);
}

public void nextQuestion()
{

}
```

}

Comment: Instead of using a 1D String, consider a 2D string ? That way you can combine frage1 to frage10 into 1 2D string array and iterate over the 1st Dimension to get to the next question and/or pass the index of current question to get to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Anupam said in the comments is correct; I believe the simplest / quickest approach is to combine your `frage` arrays in to a 2-dimensional array, which you can iterate over to get the next question.

```
private String[][] questions = {frage1, frage2, frage3, frage4, frage5, frage6, frage7}
```

Additionally, your code needs to know which question is the "next question". There are a few ways you can solve that, however since we're dealing with arrays, one approach is to maintain an "index" value, like so:

```
public class DasQuiz extends EBAnwendung {

    private int currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    ...
```

Then, your `nextQuestion` method simply uses that value to determine which question to load next

For example:

```
public void nextQuestion() {
    String[] currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];

    hatZeichenbereichQuestion.setzeInhalt(currentQuestion[0]);
    hatEtikett2.setzeInhalt(currentQuestion[1]);
    hatEtikett3.setzeInhalt(currentQuestion[2]);
    hatEtikett4.setzeInhalt(currentQuestion[3]);

    currentQuestionIndex++; // increment to the next question index
}
```

Additionally, your `hatKnopfGoGeklickt` method can simply make use of `nextQuestion`, instead of doing the work itself:

```
public void hatKnopfGoGeklickt() {
    nextQuestion();
}
```

*Side Note #1:* Be aware that I did not check for any array out-of-bounds issues in `nextQuestion` because I'm uncertain how your program works when it reaches the end of the questions (maybe its obvious, not sure as my German is a little rusty).

*Side Note #2:* You may find your code a lot cleaner if you create a class that represents a question and its corresponding answers.

**Update**

In regards to what you said in the comments about being uncertain how to make a new class, something like this would be nice and simple:

```
public class Question { // Frage
    private String questionText;
    private String[] answers;
    private String correctOption;

    public Question(String questionText, String[] answers, String correctOption){
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will implement the whole thing when I get time to do so I might be able tonight I'll let you know if it works.
I also though about the second class but I could not think of any acceptable way to make a new class worth existing

Comment: Thank you so very much both of you guys now it works perfectly and I also learned a lot from it! 
Also Mr Richer ;) your German seems to be just fine I would have taken longer to figure out the functioning of that code!

Comment: @user2859931 That's good, I'm glad it worked out. I added an extra portion to the answer showing *one* possible way you can implement your `frage` array as an object instead. Also, please remember to upvote and accept the answer (click the green checkmark to the left of the answer) if it helped you. Viel Erfolg!

Comment: @user2859931 I would have to see your project, there could be any number of reasons. Are you remembering to do the `currentQuestionIndex++;` portion in `nextQuestion()`?

Comment: @user2859931 I see you removed the comment, did you figure it out?

Comment: I can use the Go key to operate the nextQuestion task but when my Answer buttons want to use it the array does not give out the next question but keeps spamming question number one and if I leave the array within the service I can not use it outside obviously do you have any ideas on how to solve this I really am stuck I am sorry to bother you you
I'll post the code again on the top the new version I mean

Comment: @Timbo I'm going to rollback your edit shortly because if you update the code in your question, the answers don't make any sense anymore (what you can do though is add additional code at the bottom, instead of changing the existing code). Also, separate questions should be asked in separate posts too. But I think the problem is because you're doing `currentQuestion[4] == "C"`; you can't compare Strings in Java using `==`. Do `currentQuestion[4].equals("C")` instead (or possibly better: `currentQuestion[4].equalsIgnoreCase("C")`).

Comment: @Timbo Also, if you want to get the current question, I would make a method called `getCurrentQuestion()`, which simply returns `questions[currentQuestionIndex]`.